# Windows Shell Command to Show File Name and Last Access Time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a Windows command to list files and their last access times, sorted by access time.

I have used

```
dir [directory] /O:D /T:A /S /B > output.txt
```

This outputs the files in directory and sub directories in order by their last access time; however I also need it to output the last access time as well. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from within a batch file:

```
>output.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /o:d /t:a /s /b "c:\myPath\*"') @echo %%~tF %%F
)
```

***However, there are some things you need to be aware of:***

- The files are sorted by access timestamp ***within a directory***. It does ***not*** sort by access timestamp across all the directories. Your original code has the same problem. To sort accross directories requires parsing the access timestamp and converting it into a string that will sort chronologically when ordered via SORT. Something like "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm". Even that is not particularly good because you don't have access to the seconds. You could use WMIC DATAFILE to list file names with last access timestamps at a sub-second level. But why bother, considering that...
- The last access timestamp maintained by Windows is ***not reliable***! There are many situations whereby an application can read a file and yet the last access timestamp is not updated. I've seen some reference material somewhere that talks about that, but I don't remember where.

If you still think you want to get a list of files sorted by last access timestamp for an entire folder hierarchy, then the following will work. Assume you want to list all files under "c:\test\"

```
wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path like '\\test\\%'" get name, lastaccessed | sort
```

The timestamp will have the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmssddddddZZZZ` where

- YYYY = year
- MM = month
- DD = day
- hh = hour (24 hour format)
- mm = minutes
- ss = seconds
- dddddd = micro seconds
- ZZZZ = timezone, expressed as minutes difference from GMT (the 1st character is the sign)

***EDIT***

The wildcard search in WMIC causes terrible performance. Here is a version that iterates through all the folders in the root hierarchy, running WMIC against each specific folder (no wildcard). It has decent performance.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "root=c:\test"
set "output=output.txt"

set "tempFile=%temp%\dir_ts_%random%.txt"
(
  for /d /r "%root%" %%F in (.) do (
    set "folder=%%~pnxF\"
    set "drive=%%~dF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    2>nul wmic datafile where "drive='!drive!' and path='!folder:\=\\!'" get name, lastaccessed|findstr /brc:[0-9]
    endlocal
  )
) >"%tempFile%
sort "%tempFile%" >"%output%"
del "%tempFile%"
```