# Batch Directory with Attributes into csv

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, for-loop, dir

I've spent a good amount of time searching this (and other) websites trying to figure this out, but I finally admit that I'm stuck.  I'm a beginner user, so I apologize in advance if my terminology / explanation is confusing.

OS: Windows 7

I'm working on a single batch file that will create a .csv file with attributes and paths for all folders and files (including subfolders) of the batch file's current folder location.  I'm iterating this for all possible scenarios of the attributes.  Below is an explanation of my code:

**create a heading in the csv file:

```
@echo on
echo Folder vs. File,Hidden,System Folder,Read Only,Path > FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv
```

**copy file and folder names with specific attributes to a temporary .txt file

```
dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:dhsr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
```

**append the attributes to the folder / file path and place into a csv file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Hidden,System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv
```

**delete temporary .txt file

```
del FoldersAndFiles.txt
```

**The Problem(s)**
I'm not exactly sure where the problem(s) are because - for some reason - it works in certain folders, but not others.  Sometimes I only get the heading when files with known attributes are present, sometimes the full path is not present, and sometimes I get nothing at all.  I thought maybe I was overwriting the temporary file too quickly, so I created unique .txt files for each scenario, but that still didn't work.

**Below is my full code:

```
@echo off

echo Folder vs. File,Hidden,System Folder,Read Only,Path > FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:dhsr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Hidden,System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:dhs-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Hidden,System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:dh-sr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Hidden,Not System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:dh-s-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Hidden,Not System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:d-hsr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Not Hidden,System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:d-hs-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Not Hidden,System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:d-h-sr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Not Hidden,Not System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:d-h-s-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo Folder,Not Hidden,Not System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-dhsr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Hidden,System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-dhs-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Hidden,System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-dh-sr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Hidden,Not System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-dh-s-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Hidden,Not System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-d-hsr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Not Hidden,System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-d-hs-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Not Hidden,System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-d-h-sr /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Not Hidden,Not System,ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv

dir %~dp0 /s /n /a:-d-h-s-r /b >> FoldersAndFiles.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FoldersAndFiles.txt) do echo File,Not Hidden,Not System,Not ReadOnly,%%i >> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv


del FoldersAndFiles.txt
```

Thanks for your help,
Sean

Comment: Perhaps this approach can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729140/windows-shell-command-to-show-file-name-and-last-access-time. It uses different attributes, but I assume yours are accessible through wmi too. And wmic is able to create csv files.

Answer (score 0):

```
> FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv (for /f "delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /S /B /A "%~dp0*.*"') do echo %%~aI,"%%I")
```

As per [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

> Use `%~aI` to display the Extended Attributes of a file. `FOR`'s `%%~aI`
>   recognizes 9 NTFS file attributes. The expansion of a file attribute
>   produces a series of 9 dashes, with each recognized attribute
>   replacing a dash with a letter. A file with no recognized attributes
>   or with none set will expand to 9 dashes like this: `---------`

```
Attribute                    Expansion 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY     d-------- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY      -r------- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE       --a------ 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN        ---h----- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM        ----s---- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED    -----c--- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE       ------o-- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY     -------t- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT --------l
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL        ---------
```

You could make an *accurate* `csv` with headers as follows  (with filemask modified to narrow down output to reasonable size):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
> files\FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv (
  rem csv header
  echo "d","r","a","h","s","c","o","t","l","file"
  rem csv lines
  for /f "delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /S /B /A "%~1*.*" 2^>Nul
                           ') do call :display "%%~aI" "%%I"
)

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:display
:: subroutine to display file attributes as csv line
:: %1 file attributes ---------
:: %2 file name
set "attr=%~1"
set "out="%attr:~0,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~1,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~2,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~3,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~4,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~5,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~6,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~7,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~8,1%""
set "out=%out:-=%"
echo %out%,"%~2"
goto :eof
```

**Output**

```
d:\bat>D:\bat\SO\31079628new.bat *new

d:\bat>type files\FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv
"d","r","a","h","s","c","o","t","l","file"
"","","a","","","","","","","d:\bat\files\pathnew.txt"
"","r","a","","","","","","","d:\bat\files\bubu\New Text Document.txt"
"","","a","h","","","","","","d:\bat\files\numeric\New Text Document.txt"
"","","a","","","","","","","d:\bat\SO\28526273new"
"","","a","","","","","","","d:\bat\SO\31079628new.bat"
"d","","","","","","","","","d:\bat\SO\New folder"
"","","a","","","c","","","","d:\bat\SU\New Text Document.txt"

d:\bat>
```

Comment: Thanks JosefZ - Check my reply to Acini above - I think I may have found the error.  I didn't realize there were that many attributes - I'll give this a try as well.  Also, as I asked Aacini above, did you see any reason why my code wouldn't work?  I understand it's probably not the best way to do it, but I'm always looking to learn and want to make sure I don't have a false positive with my results.  Thanks again, Sean.

Comment: Just tested the code - it worked great - so simple.  I made one change and moved the "> FoldersAndFiles..." to the end.  This shortened my output to one line per folder / file.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(
echo Folder vs. File,Hidden,System,Read Only,Path
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A') do (
   set "attribs=%%~Aa"
   if "!attribs:D=!" neq "!attribs!" (set "type=Folder") else set "type=File"
   set "hidden=Not Hidden"
   if "!attribs:H=!" neq "!attribs!" set "hidden=Hidden"
   set "system=Not System"
   if "!attribs:S=!" neq "!attribs!" set "system=System"
   set "readOnly=Not Read Only"
   if "!attribs:R=!" neq "!attribs!" set "readOnly=Read Only"
   echo !type!,!hidden!,!system!,!readOnly!,%%~Fa
)
) > FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini- I think I actually found the error.  I didn't have Administrator rights on the computer I was attempting to run the script on, which created an error when trying to create a file in my C:\ folder.  I tested it on another PC (with admin rights) and it worked.  I attained the admin user / pwd today for my test computer and was able to run it on my C:\ drive.  I'm going to give your code a go, as I'm sure it's more efficient.  Out of curiosity, did you see any reason why my code wouldn't work (in case I'm falsely assuming it worked).