# How to detect NTFS compression from the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, ntfs

I would like to detect if Windows folder compression is on in the containing folder of a script.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1069033/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-the-windows-compress-this-drive-command-through-a-com

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: The answer is in [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html#attributes). Replace "." (= current directory) with a desired folder name, of course:

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /AD "." 2^>Nul') do @echo %~aI "%I"
```

`%~aI` modifier returns a string that comports with [File Attribute Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY     d-------- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY      -r------- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE       --a------ 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN        ---h----- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM        ----s---- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED    -----c--- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE       ------o-- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY     -------t- 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT --------l
```

In [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082941/3439404), there is a script that outputs a `csv` file with headers as follows (modify filemask to narrow down output to reasonable size):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
> files\FoldersAndFilesWithAttributes.csv (
  rem csv header
  echo "d","r","a","h","s","c","o","t","l","file"
  rem csv lines
  for /f "delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /S /B /A "%~1*.*" 2^>Nul
                           ') do call :display "%%~aI" "%%I"
)

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:display
:: subroutine to display file attributes as csv line
:: %1 file attributes ---------
:: %2 file name
set "attr=%~1"
set "out="%attr:~0,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~1,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~2,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~3,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~4,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~5,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~6,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~7,1%""
set "out=%out%,"%attr:~8,1%""
set "out=%out:-=%"
echo %out%,"%~2"
goto :eof
```

To limit one-liner output to just a single directory, combine appropriate file mask of `dir` command with [pipe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html). For instance, to get attributes of the current directory:

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /S /AD ".." 2^>Nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^%CD:\=\\%$"') do @echo %~aI "%~I"
```

**Output** (:

```
D:\bat\compressed folder>for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /S /AD ".." 2^>Nul ^|findstr /R /C:"^%CD:\=\\%$"') do @echo %~aI "%~I"
d----c----- "D:\bat\compressed folder"

D:\bat\compressed folder>cd ..

D:\bat>for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /S /AD ".." 2^>Nul ^|findstr /R /C:"^%CD:\=\\%$"') do @echo %~aI "%~I"
d---------- "D:\bat"

D:\bat>
```

or use simply `for %I in (.) do @echo %~aI %~fI` with the same output.

To get attributes of the current directory *and its content*:

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /S /A ".." 2^>Nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^%CD:\=\\%"') do @echo %~aI "%~I"
```

**Output**:

```
D:\bat\compressed folder>for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /S /A ".." 2^>Nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^%CD:\=\\%"') do @echo %~aI "%~I"
d----c----- "D:\bat\compressed folder"
d----c----- "D:\bat\compressed folder\Within compressed folder"
--a--c----- "D:\bat\compressed folder\Within compressed folder\xxx.csv"
--a--c----- "D:\bat\compressed folder\Within compressed folder\xxxx.csv"

D:\bat\compressed folder>
```

To get attributes of the current directory *and its subfolders* (no files):

```
for /D /R %I in (.) do @echo %~aI %~fI
```

Comment: Doesn't work on directories and doesn't display 'c' for me on(files in) a compressed folder.

Comment: Holy black magic batman!  Is there a way it can be done without a for loop, or to limit it to *just* a single directory?  I don't want to list files - there could be a lot or none - I just want to see if new files created will have the attribute in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `compact` command line utility...

> displays or alters the compression of files or directories on NTFS
>   partitions. **If used without parameters, compact displays the
>   compression state of the current directory and the files it
>   contains.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact

Here's an example of it's output just to show the general format for a large # of files (all uncompressed):

```
C:\Windows
λ compact *.exe

 Listing C:\Windows\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

    71168 :     71168 = 1.0 to 1   bfsvc.exe
    44544 :     44544 = 1.0 to 1   clspack.exe
  2871808 :   2871808 = 1.0 to 1   explorer.exe
   103424 :    103424 = 1.0 to 1   extrac32.exe
    15360 :     15360 = 1.0 to 1   fveupdate.exe
   733696 :    733696 = 1.0 to 1   HelpPane.exe
    16896 :     16896 = 1.0 to 1   hh.exe
   306688 :    306688 = 1.0 to 1   IsUninst.exe
   154112 :    154112 = 1.0 to 1   jview.exe
    19456 :     19456 = 1.0 to 1   keyhh.exe
   193536 :    193536 = 1.0 to 1   notepad.exe
   427008 :    427008 = 1.0 to 1   regedit.exe
    30720 :     30720 = 1.0 to 1   REGTLIB.EXE
    42496 :     42496 = 1.0 to 1   setdebug.exe
    67072 :     67072 = 1.0 to 1   splwow64.exe
  1372840 :   1372840 = 1.0 to 1   Sysmon.exe
    49680 :     49680 = 1.0 to 1   twunk_16.exe
    31232 :     31232 = 1.0 to 1   twunk_32.exe
    24168 :     24168 = 1.0 to 1   UnsignedThemesSvc.exe
   296960 :    296960 = 1.0 to 1   winhlp32.exe
   147456 :    147456 = 1.0 to 1   wjview.exe
    10240 :     10240 = 1.0 to 1   write.exe

Of 22 files within 1 directories
0 are compressed and 22 are not compressed.
7,030,560 total bytes of data are stored in 7,030,560 bytes.
The compression ratio is 1.0 to 1.
```

And here's a second example showing the output for sample compressed files:

```
λ compact test*.txt

 Listing C:\Users\chg0418\Documents\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

   266240 :    180224 = 1.5 to 1 C test.txt
    29970 :     28672 = 1.0 to 1 C test2.txt

Of 2 files within 1 directories
2 are compressed and 0 are not compressed.
296,210 total bytes of data are stored in 208,896 bytes.
The compression ratio is 1.4 to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the "~a" modifier in the middle of a "%v" replaced variable only returns the attributes of the folder containing the file %v, not the attributes of the file itself...

To get the actual compression status of files, use "COMPACT filanemes" to show its compression ratio.

Unfortunately this does not display directly the compression of files and which "WOFADK.SYS" method was used (XPRESS4K, XPRESS8K, XPRESS16K or LZX) for a specific executable file (non executable files use different method). NTFS native compression is not used for executables which are compressed instead using WOF/WOFADK overlay drivers (more or less acting like reparse points with a structured data storage indicating where compressed data is actually stored, it may be in another file like in WIM files, and where the page fragments of files are organized)

WOF/WOFADK compacted executable files are not shown in "blue" when you enable this setting in File Explorer: blue is used for normal data files (texts/logs, bitmaps/icons, XML, HTML, source files...). WOF can be used on top of that, and internally uses standard hidden files which may or may not be themselves using the NTFS compression. These WOF-compacted files look in Explorer as if they were not compressed, but internally the storage may be sparse and if a WOF-compacted file has common fragments (such as large spans of common data, they'll take less space, but the compresion is done on memory page size boundaries. I suppose this is done for performance reasons in the kernel so that WOF compression can avoid fragments spanning several storage pages, and I/O is then reduced, and paging can work.

NTFS file compression can be more effective, but it does not allow in situ compression and does not scale well for non-readonly files: it works only for compressing whole files at once, and for sequential read access. WOF-compaction allows random access but with a price: a more modest compression ratio. WOF-compaction also can compact multiple different executable files with internal linking to a common storage pool (that's why WIM files for Windows images are so small, about 4GB compared to their expanded size which would be about 4 times larger: WOF-compaction is global in a WIM file and works best for read-only files). WOF compaction is apparently used as well in the VHDX format for VMs; both are creating a virtual large storage space over a small physical space, but with random access for readonly operations; write operations in WOF/WIM/VHDX can be slow or will reduce the compression ratio (a background worker can reoptimize the storage if no more modifications are pending and enough idel time has passed without write access).