# How do I create a batch file that creates a list of files in a folder along with date last accessed and size?

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a batch file that creates a list of files in a folder along with date last accessed and size?

**My code is this so far:**

```
dir /b /s > fileslist.txt
```

and creates a list of the contents in the folder the batch file is located like this:

```
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\3D Designs
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\Adobe
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\AirDroid
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\Amazon Downloader Logs
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\AppScan
C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\Audacity
```

Comment: What about this command ? `dir /s /b /o:ds /A-D > fileslist.txt`

Comment: Not, what I was looking for? I like how it lists the files but, it does not show the date last accessed and size of the files or folders.

Comment: There isn't a native command that will display the path+filename+size+date all on one line.  If you use the command from @Hackoo and omit the `/b`, it will get you close to what you want.  Although the date is the last modified date, not the last access date.  Each folder is mentioned, all files are shown, file size and folder size are shown...

Comment: @dbenham figured out how to do what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730345/822072

Answer (score 1):

This should be closer to what you want:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-4*" %%A in ('dir /ta /s /a-d') do (
    if "%%A" NEQ "Directory" if "%%E" NEQ "" if "%%B" NEQ "Dir(s)" echo %%E ^|^| %%A %%B %%C %%D
)
pause
```

Output:

```
C:\fileName.ext || 2017/10/4 00:00 AM 42
```

The code does:

- Gets a list of files and folders
- Sort out necessaries strings
- Output them with a proper format, either

  - `C:\fileName.ext || [last accessed date time] [byte count]`
  - `C:\folderToTest || [last accessed date time]`

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: @JamesL.: Thanks. Do you know does `%%~tG` gives last modified date or last access date?

Comment: The `for` command with `%%~tG` pulls the last modified time, even if you add `/tc` to the `dir` command.  I created a folder (`c:\y`) and copied 2 files to it.  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730345/822072 I tried this command `wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\y\\'" get name, lastaccessed, size` and it properly pulled the size, last access date, and filename for both files.  The prior link shows how to do it for multiple paths.  I won't post as my own answer, because @dbenham really deserves the credit.

Comment: @JamesL.: I used the `dir /tc` and modified my script so it outputs access time now.

Comment: You can add `/a-d` to your `dir` command to eliminate the `.` and `..` folders.  The `/s` still traverses sub-folders.

Comment: @JamesL. I modified the script accordingly to your last comment.